# Point of convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)

How do I compute the point of convergence of a series?

e.g. for example, How do I prove that,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=1$$

Can I do:

Point of convergence=
$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=\sup\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{11}{16},\frac{13}{16},\frac{57}{64},\frac{15}{16},\dots\}=1$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) is a (near) duplicate post.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac1{1-r}$$ for $|r|<1$ and $r\ne1$

Applying derivative wrt $r,$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-r)^2}$$

Put $r=\frac12,$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac1{(1-\frac12)^2}=4$$

Now, divide both sides by $2^2$

---

Alternatively,

let $$S=1+2r+3r^2+4r^3+\cdots+ n\cdot r^{n-1}$$ with  $|r|<1$  and $r\ne1$

So, $$r\cdot S=r+2r^2+3r^3+4r^4+\cdots+(n-1)\cdot r^{n-1}+n\cdot r^n$$

On subtraction, $$(1-r)S=1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots+r^{n-1}-n\cdot r^n=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}-n\cdot r^n$$

If $n\to \infty, r\to 0$ as  $|r|<1$ , so does $n\cdot r^n$(Prove)

So, $$(1-r)S=\frac1{1-r}$$

Comment: Wonderful! Neat answer, lab. +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh, my pleasure. Please have a look into the alternative method.

Comment: Well, the second method is risky right! you never know when 1=2=1/2...

Comment: How do you draw that line just below "divide both sides by $2^2$"?

Comment: @GitGud, Do you know, you can click edit to see the actual codes? "*****" is what he did.

Comment: @GitGud, as each term after derivative is $n\cdot r^{n-1}$ but we need $n\cdot r^{n+1}$

Comment: @Freddy, what did you mean by $1=2=\frac12?$

Comment: @Freddy Thanks.
@ labbhattacharjee, You misunderstood my question. I got it now anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I realized, its fine here. What I was refering to 1-1+1-1+1... and the old trick of showing that 0=1=1/2 or something. But we have convergent series and it's fine.

Comment: @DavidMitra, thanks for your instructive feedback, rectified.

Answer (score 2):

If we denote S=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\displaystyle \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$, then

$$S-\frac{S}{2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}\longrightarrow S=1$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: It's really clever method! Thanks!

Comment: @Freddy: thank you! :-)